# Code for checking if file/record already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an application that allows you to upload and download files.

During creation of files, I want to go into the database and check if the same file no already exists and also check if a field called VendorId is the same as the vendor id they are trying to create.

For example:
[image: List view]
In this image, you can see I have two files already existing with the same file no, but they have different VendorId's assigned.

[image: Creating a file]

When creating a file they enter a file no, and type and then select a vendor to assign the file to.

If they try to create another file with the same file number AND also the same vendorId then I want an error to occur.

The problem I have with the following code is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var file = _context.Files.Where(x =>x.Number ==Files.Number).FirstOrDefault();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            if (file == null || (file.FileType != Files.FileType) || (file.VendorId != Files.VendorId))
            {
       
                    _context.Files.Add(Files);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    if (Files.FileType == "Purchase Order")
                    {
                        return LocalRedirect("~/PurchaseOrders");
                    }
                    else if (Files.FileType == "Remittance")
                    {
                        return LocalRedirect("~/Remittance");
                    }
                    else if (Files.FileType == "Growers Return")
                    {
                        return LocalRedirect("~/GrowersReturn");
                    }
                    else if (Files.FileType == "Haulage Self Bill")
                    {
                        return LocalRedirect("~/HaulageSelfBill");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["error"] = "Exists";
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

That once it finds a file with the same file number, it stops there and I need it to repeat and check for every file in the db.

Can someone advise how I would change my code to reflect this?

Comment: Sorry, you need to clear up a bit about what exactly you're asking.
I couldn't see any database code in the snippet you provided.

Comment: `var file = _context.Files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == Files.Number && x.Vendor == Files.Vendor)` then `bool fileExists = file != null`

Comment: @PauloSantos the code to interact with the db is the following: `var file = _context.Files.Where(x =>x.Number ==Files.Number).FirstOrDefault();`.

Comment: @MeganPaterson You're welcome, let me know if it works and I'll create the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for both conditions (vendor and no) in the predicate of **FirstOrDefault** `var file = _context.Files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == Files.Number && x.Vendor == Files.Vendor)`. It will be NULL if it doesn't exist (because FirstOrDefault returns NULL if no element is matched)

Note that in your original code you were using **Where** then **FirstOrDefault** when **FirstOrDefault** already iterates all the items (so you were iterating twice)